# How to generate database diagram automatically? mysql

Tags: mysql

How can i generate database diagrams from my database automatically in mysql? I saw mysql workbench and it's very nice except for the fact that it doesn't allow me to copy the diagrams to clipboard and save it in MS Word. Please help.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does PDF export help you? Looks like you can export to PDF, PNG etc http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/features.html